# Cómo pasar (si se puede) dirección de una variable modificada en driver.c a su test.c con CppUtest

Tags: c, linux, unity

Me encuentro ante un conflicto entre el test de un driver y su driver cuando ejecuto el test (dos ficheros con sus headers de dependencia). Sé cual es la fuente de conflicto (un parámetro que no es el esperado) y por qué sucede, pero no la alternativa.

Todos los libros y ejemplos consultados no especifican si aquello que trato de hacer en el mundo de los tests es "legal" o no. Tengo la ligera sospecha que no se debe hacer y por tanto implica error en la arquitectura de la fuente. Básicamente mi intuición es tal por la información que he podido hallar. Por la omisión de casos como el que pretendo resolver, interpreto que quizás esté "prohibido". Pero antes quiero asegurarme que realmente no haya herramientas en cpputest para llevarlo a cabo.

Me encuentro que no puedo pasar la dirección de una variable X (por simplificar) -desde el código fuente- a su código test (para usarla de parámetro de entrada en una función mockeada en el test). ¿Existe alguna forma de compartir el valor de una dirección de una variable modificada en un driver.c y llevarla como parámetro a una llamada de una función mockeada -dentro de su test.c-?

Ejemplo:

*Driver.c:*

```
void init(*structinit)
{
  uint8_t X = 0;

  // ...

  X = a + b; //supongamos q a y b son otras operaciones tratadas con mascaras y algunas mas complejas operaciones

  funcion(&X);

  // ...

}
```

*TEST Drivertest.c:*

```
{
  // ...

  mock().expectonecall("funcion").withParameter("pcbuffer",&X);

  // ...
}
```

Digamos que para compilar me veo obligada a declarar X también en el test. Aquí es donde empieza la ambigüedad. Porque me obligo a crear dos direcciones para el mismo parámetro y resultará en fallo de parámetro no esperado. 
¿Es una mala praxis o realmente hay una forma correcta de pasar una variable desde el código a testear a su test?

Las funciones del driver llaman a otras funciones de más bajo nivel, de hardware. Si no hay hardware el driver se quedaría colgado y etc.. porque no tiene su respuesta. La función funcion está implementada en otro fichero -que no forma parte del paquete del test-. En su lugar usamos los mocks(). Simulan llamadas con o sin retorno a sistema (definidas e impuestas por el test). Toda llamada a función mock() actúa de simuladora de la llamada espejo en el driver. Hay una vinculación de forma que cuando el test detecta que el driver llama a funcion() el mock que ves arriba sustituye a funcion() pasando valores concretos (imaginación al poder por parte del tester) y devuelve los valores que hemos grabado según el supuesto de la situación fingida. Supongamos que funcion() ha sido diseñada para devolver un (0) cuando driver realice la llamada espejo.

No puedo transformar la variable byte del driver local en global sólo para que me pase el test porque estaría violando un principio del testing, los códigos fuente son intocables para la persona tester. Pero si detecto mediante el test problemas de arquitectura debo ponerlo en conocimiento.

Comment: Tu pregunta parece un poco ambigua. ¿Qué se supone que hace `fucnion`? ¿Dónde está declarada? ¿Por qué es imprescindible pasarle un puntero a la `X` declarada en `driver.c`? Por otro lado en tu código no estás duplicando la variable... estás creando una variable diferente e independiente.

Comment: El test (o la mayoría de entorno de test como cpputest) exige que los parámetros coincidan tanto en el mock (lado/fichero test) como en la llamada del código driver. expectonecall significa que el test espera que el driver en ese punto del hilo haga esa llamada con esos parámetros y entonces le pasa los valores acordados desde el mock. Compara los parámetros y si hay alguna discordancia extrae por consola un mensaje de error.

Comment: Que verifique que sean iguales no debería implicar que comparase direcciones de memoria sino los valores apuntados por dichos punteros. Si esto no es posible deberiás plantearte cambiar `funcion` para que admita el dato por valor en vez de por puntero.

Comment: Son dos direcciones distintas porque la variable ha sido creada dos veces. El problema radica en que deben confluir y ser idénticas tanto en mock()funcion como en funcion().

Comment: Claro si le paso el dato y no la dirección se acabó el problema. Pero esa versión implica tocar el código fuente y yo tengo permiso acceso al código fuente del driver. Más lo único que puedo es indicar si el test me ha llevado a detectar un error de estructura en el desarrollo del driver. Digamos que salvo tratarse de un grave error de desarrollo estoy obligada a pasarle un puntero tal como se me especifica por parte de la llamada del driver, que quiere un puntero para indicar dónde se encuentran los datos. Tipo ya sabes lecturas y escrituras de registro donde aparecen buffers.

Comment: Si la variable `X` es local a nivel de `init` **no va a existir** fuera de dicha función bajo ninguna circunstancia. Luego lo que estás proponiendo no va a funcionar (Y si funciona es porque no está comparando punteros sino los valores apuntados). La solución más rápida entonces sería que `X` fuese global a nivel de `driver.c` y habilitar una función en `driver.h` que expusiese la dirección de memoria de `X`.

Comment: Eso está claro. Pero a nivel testing, con estos frameworks que abren  puertas a nuevas opciones, como cpputest, que no domino quizás exista alguna opción. Permite opciones de paso de parámetros, datos y objetos entre módulos que para un desarrollador de código fuente no son habituales. Si permite pasar el retorno y otros parámetros desde un mock del fichero test hacia el fichero driver, tal vez a la inversa sí se pueda. Pero desconozco si existe opción inversa y esa es la cosa que ando verificando. Así que si alguien a nivel testing sabe si existe o si no, le agradezco aclaración.